# Android Volley newRequestQueue - Incompatible types

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm making application for getting data from server with Volley. But when I need to get request:

```
rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Getting this error

[image]

I already set INTERNET permission in Manifest and also in app set: compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

My all code:

```
package com.example.doma.fp;

import android.net.http.RequestQueue;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RequestQueue rq ;
    TextView nameText;

    String name;

    String url = "http://127.0.0.1/OOP/database/android.php";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        nameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textname);

      //  sendjsonrequest();

    }

    public void sendjsonrequest()
    {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    name = response.getString("name");

                    nameText.setText(name);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });


    }

}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you've imported the wrong class...
This

```
import android.net.http.RequestQueue;
```

supposed to be -

```
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have imported android.net.http.RequestQueue instead of com.android.volley.RequestQueue;